# Selenium click print button to open print dialog, but blocked

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, printing

Selenium click print button to open print dialog, but blocked.

```
 <button id="print" onclick="window.print()"/>


 WebElement print = driver.findElement(By.id("print"));
 print.click();   // blocked here

 // use the Robot to close print dialog
```

The print preview window is opened after clicking the print button. but the print.click() is blocked until I close the print dialog manually. Is the a way to tell Selenium to return immediately after clicking the button?

Comment: Can you explain more what you wanted to achieve here ? and why are you closing the dialog manually ?